# Change Meteor Node-Inspector web-port

Tags: debugging, meteor, port, node-inspector

I need to change the web-port used by `node-inspector` when debugging Meteor but it seems to always run on 8080, which is where I need to run the Meteor web app.

I've tried setting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable before running Meteor:

```
$ export NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=47977
$ meteor debug --port=8080
[[[[[ ~/.../src ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.                              
=> Started MongoDB.                           
   Starting your app                         -
Your application is now paused and ready for debugging!

To debug the server process using a graphical debugging interface, 
visit this URL in your web browser:
http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858

Paused at /.../src/.meteor/local/build/main.js:7
Cannot start the server at 0.0.0.0:8080. Error: listen EADDRINUSE.
There is another process already listening at this address. 
Run `node-inspector --web-port={port}` to use a different port.
```

I've tried running node-inspector separately on a different web port then starting meteor, but meteor always seems to also try starting node-inspector on 8080:

```
$ node-inspector --web-port=47977 &
[1] 74439
$ Node Inspector v0.5.0
   info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:47977/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.

$ meteor debug --port=8080
[[[[[ ~/.../src ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
   Starting your app                         -
Your application is now paused and ready for debugging!

To debug the server process using a graphical debugging interface, 
visit this URL in your web browser:
http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858

Paused at /.../src/.meteor/local/build/main.js:7
Cannot start the server at 0.0.0.0:8080. Error: listen EADDRINUSE.
There is another process already listening at this address.
Run `node-inspector --web-port={port}` to use a different port.
```

Note, there are 3 ports in play here:

1. 8080 - Web port running Meteor web app.
2. 47977 - Web port I want to run node-inspector web app.
3. 5858 - Port used to communicate between the other 2 processes.

I need Meteor to be running on 8080 but can't seem to stop Meteor starting node-inspector on 8080 too. I've also tried a few other ports for node-inspector but with the same results.

Running on Mac with Meteor 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i've solved by:

in terminal run `node-inspector --web-port=47977`

and in a new terminal run `meteor debug`

go to `http://127.0.0.1:47977/ws=127.0.0.1:47977&port=5858` to start debugging.